# On Fail Message for SQL Formatted ChangeSets

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I can add preconditions to formatted SQL scripts, like [the docs](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) say:

```
--preconditions onFail:HALT onError:HALT
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

but I can't seem to add an `onFailMessage` or `onErrorMessage` to them.

Is there a way I've missed?

Or should I just code up something like
`--precondition-onFailMessage:Better luck next time`
and send a PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, `onFailMessage` and `onErrorMessage` attributes are not supported for SQL formatted changeSets.

I believe [FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java) parses SQL formatted changeSets.

And I just can't find parsers for `onFailMessage` or `onErrorMessage` in this class, so I believe these attributes are just getting ignored.

The correct code should be (if it was getting parsed):

`--preconditions onFail:HALT onError:HALT onFailMessage:your_message`

So `--precondition-onFailMessage:Better luck next time` won't do anything to your changeSets, so I suppose there's no need to include it in your PR.

Comment: Yeah, I read that same class before asking the question, just didn't mention it. If that's the expected format I can easily code it up and send a PR.

Comment: Oh, so I guess you should! Thanks!

Comment: For the benefit of googlers, the PR is here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/1150